# Thread interference when calling synchronized queue methods

Tags: java, multithreading

Running my program, which is multithreaded, seems to lead to *thread interference* even though I used the keyword *synchronized* for the methods that have an effect on the part where my problem lies.

I have a *static nested class* **Station** which has the following methods in it:

```
public synchronized boolean addQueuer(String ID)
{
    if (!buffer.isFull())
    {
        buffer.enqueue(ID);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

private synchronized void removeQueuer()
{
    buffer.dequeue();
}
```

*Buffer is a simple queue with wrapping.*

In two different threads, I call these methods. In the encapsulator, the main method has the following lines of code:

```
while (true)
{
    stations[0].addQueuer("M");
    Thread.sleep(FREQ_TIMER);
}
```

Where stations is an array of **Station** containg a single station in my test

And in **Station** I have the following *run()* function for implementation of Runnable (I start a thread by creating an instance of this class, then call *start()* for this thread):

```
public void run()
{
    try
    {
        Thread.sleep(ESTIMATED_SERVICE_TIME);

        while (!buffer.isEmpty())
        {
            removeQueuer();
        }
        if (isOpen)
            run();
    } catch (InterruptedException interruptException)
    {
        threadMessage("This station was interrupted.");
    }
}
```

---

*What is going wrong:*

I have adjusted the **CONSTANTS** so that the buffer should fill up quicker than it gets emptied. However, when I run my program the buffer might start at 7, go down to 6 at next run in the next loop, then it will stay at 6 forever.

---

*First, it is not possible for two invocations of synchronized methods on the same object to interleave. When one thread is executing a synchronized method for an object, all other threads that invoke synchronized methods for the same object block (suspend execution) until the first thread is done with the object.* - [Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html)

Why is it not enough to put synchronize? If any additional context/information is required, please comment and I'll try abide.

Edit: Added [the entire code](http://pastebin.com/sLJ7F6cc).

Comment: I think you misunderstand the meaning of the synchronized keyword. It is important to understand what gets 'locked' when using synchronized. You want to synchronize over the buffer itself in this case since many threads can access the buffer. If you post more of your source we might be able to help.

Comment: You use the `buffer` without synchronization in your `run()` method: `!buffer.isEmpty()`

Comment: @RudolphEst I added the whole code, its commented so its not all 270 lines of code.

Comment: Your buffer is static, which means it is shared across all stations.  I'm guessing you don't want that.

Comment: You have to lock the critical sections completely, this means between checking whether the buffer is not empty and modifying the buffer you must not release the locks. This is not what can be done with multiple synchronized methods. Instead you could e.g. use `synchronized(buffer) { critica code }`

Comment: see e.g. [Synchronized Statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html)

Comment: @tomse Thank you Tomse, this I did not know. However, if I've done it correct now, it still doesn't work for some reason. For both removeQueuer() and addQueuer(), I put the entire code inside a synchronized(buffer) { //Code here }, also for run() I put the while loop inside a synchronized(buffer) { //while loop in here }

Comment: I'll add that if it now starts at 7 (buffer size) it stays at 7 indefinitely instead.